# Opening an excel file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to just call Open() function with the file name and extension (xlApp.Workbooks.Open(“Test.xlsx”)) and have it search your whole computer for the file? I know you can open the file if it has a specified path like "c:\docume~1(username)\desktop\Test.xlsx" but I was wondering if there's a way to search your whole computer for the file without specifying the whole path.

Comment: You could write a very slow recursive script to do this for you, but afaik, there is nothing built in.

Comment: Of course not. Suppose there were 20 different `Test.xlsx` files in different folders on two separate disk drives. Which one should it open? You need to specify the specific path and filename.

Comment: @KenWhite I understand that. They need to make a function that does this and finds multiple files then it should open a window and have all the files and with their path and let you select which one is the correct file.

Comment: Josh, they do. It's called `Windows Explorer`. :-) If you need that functionality, write it; it's called programming. The majority of people apparently don't have that need, or MS would have added it to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "yourFile.xls", 
                                   SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

or

```
var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\", "yourFiles.xls", 
                                        SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

but you should read carefully the documentation [(GetFiles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316) [(EnumerateFiles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571) on MSDN because there are numerous facts to be prepared of. *(Unauthorized Access Exceptions, Search times)*

Comment: Sorry if this sounds dumb but why do u have "string[] fileNames"? Can I just make a string variable that contains the file name and then use it that way?...

Comment: Because the `Directory.GetFiles` method returns a string array. You could test the `fileNames.Length` to know if you have found your file (or more than one in different paths). Then you use `fileNames[0]` to read the full path of the first file found.

Comment: Well thanks for helping but I couldn't get it to work so I just got the username of the person who is currently logged in and then make them have the file in a certain place on their computer...Not the best way but it works....Thanks