# Open Excel Workbook from ComboBox (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, excel, file-io, combobox

How to open an excel workbook from combobox?

I am using following code to populate combobox with excel filenames,

```
Dim files() As String
files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Files\Folder", "*.xlsx", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
For Each FileName As String In files
ComboBox1.Items.Add(FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1, FileName.Length -     FileName.LastIndexOf("\") - 1))
Next
```

But I do not have any idea about how to open the selected file.

Comment: Do you want to just open the Excel file or do you want to further interact with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections

Public Class Form1

Private Const TargetDir = "C:\Files\Folder"
Private FullFileList As List(Of String)


Private Sub ProcessFile(ByVal fn As String)
    If Path.GetExtension(fn).ToLower = ".xlsx" Then
        FullFileList.Add(fn)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(fn))
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String)
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
    Dim fileName As String
    For Each fileName In fileEntries
        ProcessFile(fileName)
    Next fileName
    Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
    Dim subdirectory As String
    For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
    Next subdirectory
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FullFileList = New List(Of String)
    ProcessDirectory(TargetDir)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim prc As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(FullFileList(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex))
        psi.UseShellExecute = True
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        prc.StartInfo = psi
        prc.Start()
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: just one small query, under "GetFile" if we are searching in all sub directories then how do we open selected file?

Comment: In that case you'll need to keep a seperate list of full paths, I'll update my answer. Give me a moment and I'll do a few other mods to how I'd normally do it.

Comment: Just updated - actually your original code didn't work as I thought it would have so used an example from MSDN to recurse directories along with my original code to launch Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`Process.start("excel "+ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());`

on buttonclick event

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It gives an error "can not find file specified". Which is understandable as I am adding only filenames to combobox. But when I use "GetFile" it gets the filepath. Is there any way to show only filename and while opening file use entire file path?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle an event to react to the user's selection: either a change to the selection in the `ComboBox` or (better) a `Button` click. In your event handler you can retrieve the filename from the `ComboBox`:

```
string filename = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Once you have the filename, you can open the file, although how you do this will depend on what you want to do with it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11978301/976080) has some information on opening Excel files in VB.NET.